# Why must I make a self created array optional in a class init(), but not a preexisting variable type?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I've created a an array of Ints which I use when creating multiple icons, which are in an array as well

```
enum Nodes : Int
{
    case ball = 0,
    bat,
    base
}

let iconType :[Nodes] = [
    . ball,
    . bat,
    . base
]
```

I've given MyIcons two properties, one is String, and the other the array I created, iconType. I don't have to make the String variable optional, yet if I don't make the array optional I get the error:

> Property 'self.nodeType' not initialized at super.init call

Is this normal? Or am I doing something incorrectly?

```
class MyIcons : SKSpriteNode{
    var fileName    : String
    var nodeType    : Nodes?
    
    init(wIcon: String, iNode: Nodes, iSize: CGSize) {
        fileName = wIcon
        let skTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: fileName)
        super.init(texture: skTexture, color: .black, size: .zero)
        self.name = fileName
        self.nodeType = iNode
        self.isHidden = true
        self.zPosition = theZ.wIcons
        self.size.width = iSize.width
        self.size.height = iSize.height
        wheelScene?.addChild(self)
        self.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        self.position = CGPoint(x: (wheelScene?.frame.width)!/2, y: (wheelScene?.frame.height)!/2)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `self.nodeType = iNode` before `super.init`.

Comment: @Sweeper I swear I tried that, and got the "using self before initialized" error. But now I'm not. I must have done some sort of typo. Thank you